# how to join a local user to a domain controller?

Tags: active-directory

IS there any possible that the local user of a pc join to a domain controller?
I have some user who have a lot of setting in the local user account and don't want to set them again?
thanks for your helping...

Comment: No there isn't but there are a number of ways that you can copy their local user profile to their domain user profile.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the domain and use a tool (such as ForensiT) to export all settings from the local account to the new domain account on the pc.